# Log to console in a Lightning Web Component

Tags: error, lightning-web-components, console, vs-code

I am attempting to write a Lightning Web Component, but continually run into errors in my Javascript that I can't debug.

I've been trying to log my error but when I put `console.log()` anywhere in the methods that are failing, I get the error:

> Unexpected console statement.

Comment: Surprisingly console.log() work in [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground)

Comment: That must be the ESLint error. You can still use `console.log()` or say `alert()` statements for any debugging purposes (I can confirm this as I have used this in couple of my LWCs).

Comment: @JayantDas anything to supress linter error?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Looks like [there's one](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) for such cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are most likely encountering ESLint errors in VS Code.

As an example below is how my code looks like with those warnings. However I am still able to save the component and utilize `alert` or `console.log` statements **specifically for debugging purposes**.

Your options are:

1. Just ignore those warnings
2. You can choose to suppress those warnings by right clicking on those to suppress either for that particular line or whole file. It though introduces following comments in your file.

   If you choose for whole file, the following is added in your file

   ```
   /* eslint-disable no-console */
   ```

   If you choose for specific line, the following is added before every such line

   ```
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
   ```
3. By editing the `.eslintrc.json` available in your project by adding the below rules. This way you don't have to address individual files. (My preferred way)

   ```
   "rules": {
       "no-console": "off",
       "no-alert": "off"
   }
   ```

---

**Console showing errors**

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks. I tried same in Illuminated Cloud for LWC, it showed `SUCCEEDED_PARTIAL`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I updated my answer to include how to add the rules in `.eslintrc.json` in VS Code.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks. btw, thanks for all your help. I don't mean to be a bug asking all these questions, it's just hard finding documentation for non-aura components.