# Console.log in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to put debug log in LWC but getting this error

[image]

Even after adding

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
```

and

```
"rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-alert": "off"
}
```

Bascially I haved added everything mentioned in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251270/log-to-console-in-a-lightning-web-component)

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getValue from '@salesforce/apex/ScController.getValue';

export default class ScScoreCard extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getValue, {opportunityId: '$recordId'}) valueList;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(">>> valueList... "+valueList);
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to put "executable statements" inside a function. For example, if you wanted to call it during construction:

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getValue from '@salesforce/apex/ScController.getValue';

export default class ScScoreCard extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getValue, {opportunityId: '$recordId'}) valueList;

    constructor() {
        super(); // Must be called first
        console.log(">>> valueList... "+valueList);
    }
}
```

Of course, this won't actually work, since the data won't be there yet. You need to write a function to handle the results:

```
import { LightningElement,track,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getValue from '@salesforce/apex/ScController.getValue';

export default class ScScoreCard extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track results;
    @wire(getValue, {opportunityId: '$recordId'}) 
    valueList({ error, data }) {
        console.log(data);
        this.results = data;
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI @sfdcfox should the track decorator be apart of the import list along with LightningElelment , api and wire? JUst want to be sure because I may need this solution soon. Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams yes.